# Critique my [windows-7] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I haven't seen any other tag wiki<sup>1</sup> pages on Super User yet, so I didn't have anything to compare it to as I wrote up the new [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) tag wiki page. What do you think? If you can edit it, go right ahead, otherwise, please let me know what I can change!

<sup>1</sup> If you aren't aware of the tag wiki pages, [see this Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57992/so-whats-this-tag-wiki-thing).

---

[image: Windows 7 Logo]

Released in October 2009, Windows 7 is Microsoft's latest operating system.

#### What is Windows 7?

> Your PC, simplified
>
> You told us to make Windows simpler and easier to use. We listened. Windows 7 has better ways to find and manage files—like [Jump Lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and improved [taskbar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) previews—to help you speed through everyday tasks. It's designed for faster and more reliable performance, so your PC just works the way you want it to. With [64-bit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) support, you can take full advantage of the latest powerful PCs. And great features like [HomeGroup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), [Windows Media Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), and [Windows Touch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) make new things possible.
>
> <sub>- From microsoft.com: *[What is Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)*</sub>

#### Related Super User questions:

- [What are some "must-have" Windows programs?](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714102545/http://superuser.com:80/questions/1241/what-are-some-must-have-windows-programs)<sup>1</sup>
- [Free antivirus solutions for Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20110903144251/http://superuser.com:80/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows)<sup>1</sup>
- [Windows 7 Tips and Tricks](https://web.archive.org/web/20110904044714/http://superuser.com:80/questions/7622/windows-7-tips-and-tricks)
- [What can be done in Windows 7 that can't be done in Windows XP?](https://web.archive.org/web/20110906142018/http://superuser.com:80/questions/14147/what-can-be-done-in-windows-7-that-cant-be-done-in-windows-xp)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Applies to all versions of Windows, not just Windows 7</sub>

#### Helpful Links:

- [Microsoft's Hardware and Software Compatibility Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/)
- [Which version is right for me?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- [Windows 7 FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20110330091703/http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/faq.aspx)

#### [Minimum hardware requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-system-requirements-df0900f2-3513-a851-13e7-0d50bc24e15f):

```
Architecture    32-bit                  64-bit
Processor       1 GHz 32-bit processor  1 GHz 64-bit processor
Memory (RAM)    1 GB                    2 GB
HDD free space  16 GB free space        20 GB free space
Graphics card   DirectX 9 graphics processor with WDDM driver model 1.0
Optical drive   DVD drive (only to install from DVD media)
```

Comment: Looking good! It should probably include some of the high view questions like: Must have Windows software and performance tweaks for Windows

Comment: @Ivo is there a way to sort by views on SU? I can't find any way to see the most-viewed [windows-7] questions...

Comment: @Ivo, added a few questions - any more you think should go on there?

Comment: @Jared: You could add this: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware

Comment: I made it CW, so anyone else could help adding links to (though no abusing here!) And as for your view sorting: I search for `views:5000` to get the more relevant questions. Though you'll be amazed what questions get massive amounts of views

Comment: +1 - Didn't even know about this feature! Good work to you for filling out the info and the SO team for adding the feature!

Comment: The first three of the related questions no longer exist.

Comment: @RandolphWest Now all of them don't exist...

Answer (score 17):

That "What is Windows 7" section reads like an advertisement - I think the tone should be more like Wikipedia rather than `microsoft.com`.

Comment: If you check how long the [feature part on Wikipedia is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7), I don't mind having just this short piece of marketing talk

Comment: It sounds like it because it's Microsoft's one-paragraph description of Windows 7 (click the "What is Windows 7" link). Our tag wiki pages should be fairly short and to the point - as @Ivo pointed out, Wikipedia's Windows 7 page is information overload.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I updated the page with some SU questions, and I made it more clear that the paragraph is from Microsoft.

Comment: @Jared - even if made more clear, it's really looking like a sponsored page, then. I think we will need to find a less "it's going to be a revolution" speech.

Comment: Or Microsoft should indeed sponsor the page @Gnoupi

Comment: @Ivo - I don't think Microsoft is likely to, they don't sponsor anything on SO on their products already, so I doubt they will for SU.