# Software Solicitation and Web-based Answers?

Tags: discussion

Super User is about computer software, hardware, and personal networking per the FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

The point that Super User is *not* about Web Applications is [well-discussed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/821/super-user-website-applications-policy).

**Are questions that *ask for software*, that start with "I need software that does..." appropriate?**

**If so, would answers that suggest Web-based options okay?**

For example, this question on file sharing/collaboration is [relatively platform-agnostic](https://superuser.com/questions/51792/what-tool-can-i-use-to-allow-multiple-teams-to-share-files), though many of the answers reference websites.

Comment: I think it's well discussed [Since when are software recommendations off-topic?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3515) [Recommendations for the BEST?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3510)

Comment: the linked question is about 3 years old, thinks were different then, the policies on recommendations weren't firm. Having said that, there is nothing wrong in providing web-based options - unless OP specifically mentioned they don't want it

Answer (score 4):

Answers must adhere to a different set of rules than questions, like actually attempting to answer the question. Answers directing users to web applications are OK. You can even [leave out the software and hardware from your answer entirely](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3413/22317), as long as the *question* satisfies the requirements *for questions*.

---

The "product recommendation" part of your question has been discussed before. There's no really clear consensus, other than that asking for programs isn't a good idea. Answers that recommend products OTOH are fine.

My suggestion: State your problem ("*I want to rename two bazillion files according to the following rules*") instead of what your solution might look like ("*please recommend a batch file renamer*"). You might be surprised what your OS (e.g. command line) already can do, for example.