# Should you answer a question that you know will get closed?

Tags: discussion, answers, migration

There are questions on SU that are sure to be closed for a variety of reasons.  Should you post an answer if you have one?  I would think so its OK if you know it will get migrated to another SE site.  But, what of one that violates the FAQ?  Is that encouraging bad behavior, or being altruistic?

Comment: There's no official policy on this (that I'm aware of) - it's really up to you and how you want to allocate your question-answering resources. If the question is good enough for you to give an answer, you might consider putting some thought towards editing the question to save it from being closed - thereby saving your answer, too!

Comment: Related: [Should humorous/funny questions be deleted from Super User?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3332/should-humorous-funny-questions-be-deleted-from-super-user)  I'm of the opinion that you're more than welcome to ask whatever you'd like, even at risk of the question being closed.  I would, however, avoid questions that I know might be **deleted**.  Even closed questions still have some merit or use on Super User (especially the more popular ones); however, deleted ones in general do not (as only high-ranking users or moderators can see them).

Comment: @Breakthrough: Don't forget, too many deleted questions might lead to a question ban.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its definitely fine if you know it gets migrated. As for against the FAQ, I usually tend to hint at an answer when I comment to why I am close voting a post. Some questions are actually interesting enough that I post an answer, then ask, and occasionally when I really KNOW I ought to comment, but it's too long, I've been guilty of posting it as a community wiki - tho I've taken to putting that rep in a pool and bountying it instead.

There's no official policy, and I think its a good thing. You're taking a calculated risk - a closed question can potentially mean lost rep should it be deleted. Trying to answer the question might also help get ideas on how to save it. On occation, halfway through the answer, you realise its an unsalvagable mess, but you learn something new.

I guess as with anything, if its an interesting enough bad question, its worth trying to answer, simply for the learning experience. Someone with a pattern of bad questions will get question banned anyway ;p

Comment: +1 Well, rep isnt everything.  I think its just a matter of pride seeing a good answer go down the drain.  :D

Comment: I like the CW idea. There's [some questions](http://superuser.com/questions/600123/multiple-access-point-equipment-and-cautions/600143) that I would like to answer but I feel silly gaining any rep from, and even sillier answering the question when I know my name will end up on `Closed by:`. Seems like a good way to sidestep the issue.

Comment: CW isn't really meant to be a rep-free card - its purpose was originally to allow community collaboration, which is now mostly unnecessary with the advent of suggested edits. If you have a _lot_ of people contributing to a single post it makes sense, but try not to use it as "I don't feel like getting rep for this".

Comment: eh, I guess so. Edited to make it clear using CW as a rep free card is a bit of an abuse. ;p

Comment: You need those bounty contests again, @JourneymanGeek

Comment: I don't mind giving away the rep. I just keep forgetting ;p

Comment: @Keltari /s/everything/anything - fixed.

Comment: oh, up to a point, rep is pretty neat - more importantly, the privileges it unlocks. When you pass 20K tho, its just a number.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - With regard to the loss of reputation you wouldn't be any worst of if you just ignore the question so you have nothing to lose but time and any future reputation points you gleem from it.

Comment: Oh, its not about rep at all. The real benefit from an answer is really having to write an answer in a way a third party can understand, and where its necessary, the research behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what the close reason is.

If it's borderline and/or you think it belongs on the site despite the claims, answer. But do know that it's in everyone's best interest if you spend a little time editing the question so that it falls on the very well on topic side of things.

If it's off topic or not a real question, move onto something else. Answering these is like saying it's okay to post because you'll get an answer anyway.

The same as if someone cut in line and instead of being sent to the back, are served and treated as if they were in the right place. It breeds a mindset that it's okay to not be a part of the civil community.

If it's too localised, that's either or. If you can make it not too localised, go for it.