# Is it impolite to give an answer as comment when a question is (getting) closed?

Tags: discussion

I just see the case of a new guy that posts 2 questions

1. https://superuser.com/questions/1000071/tool-for-making-beautify
2. https://superuser.com/questions/1000070/advanced-code-compare-multiple-line-regex

that are probably getting closed because they can imply a software suggestion.
I appreciate the effort of the guy to separate different aspect of his problem in different question, even clean.

**Is it considered unpolite to give an answer as comment when a question is (getting) closed?**

Comment: I personally have gotten into the bad habit of when I know the question is extremely poor to still try and help.  I don't suggest you copy my behavior though.

Comment: @Ramhound Too late... I did it too... Seldom it's not a pure question of (my) mood, but I think that the OP tried for what he/she could do... and even if the result is  poor, it is at the same time close to the best that was in the possibility of the OP (in that moment)... so I comment or answer

Comment: Similar question: [Should you answer a question that you know will get closed?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6814/should-you-answer-a-question-that-you-know-will-get-closed?rq=1)

Comment: Another: [Should I answer off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions) - "Generally speaking, answering questions that should get closed encourages bad behavior."

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I wouldn't recommend doing it all the time, but I *sometimes* do that myself with an admonition to what's on topic here.

Comment: _"The more [unpolite](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3913/3913-h/3913-h.htm) I was with people, the more obstinate they became"_ from _The Confessions of Jean Jacques Rousseau_, [[translated 1783](https://books.google.com/books?id=C1uXah12nHgC&pg=PA1197&lpg=PA1197&dq=confessions+of+jean-jacques+rousseau+first+translation&source=bl&ots=im7A3Wbn_F&sig=AbhgnjW5JebmuQ0mB5JYd-oY9qg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIscPBpcCNyQIVZGdyCh1ASgS2#v=onepage&q=confessions%20of%20jean-jacques%20rousseau%20first%20translation&f=false)], now less used. Thanks for bringing me to a more _polite_ and present use.:)

Comment: Oh. That was intentional? In which case feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: I only remembered that word from the school times, but now, thanks to you, I know that [unpolite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unpolite) it is less used than [impolite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impolite), that is even _elder_ [First Known Use: 1739]. I always try to learn, at least I try, after I will forget ;-)

Comment: "[If it's off topic or not a real question, move onto something else. Answering these is like saying it's okay to post because you'll get an answer anyway.](http://meta.superuser.com/a/6818/23133)"

Answer (score 0):

If the question gets closed with no answer, the system will delete it, anyway.  The OP may be unfamiliar with the rules and is often a one-time visitor, so there's limited value, for them, in making an issue of it by refusing to provide any information.  If it's a serious question, they seem well intentioned, and you can help them with no effort, I don't see a downside in providing information in a **comment**, along with advice that the question is off-topic.