# Merge questions about Windows symlinks

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, canonical-answer, community-faq

The best answer IMO is grawity's bold headings: https://superuser.com/a/347946/24500

[What is the difference between NTFS hard links and directory junctions?](https://superuser.com/q/67870/24500)

[Windows 7: hard link, symbolic link and junction](https://superuser.com/q/141716/24500)

[When would one prefer a Junction Point (Directory Hard Link) over a symbolic link?](https://superuser.com/q/191381/24500)

["directory junction" vs "directory symbolic link"?](https://superuser.com/q/343074/24500)

[what is the difference between a symlink , junction , hard link and so on?](https://superuser.com/q/181672/24500)

[What are hardlinks on windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/230396/24500)

[What are the advantages of symlinks over hard links and viceversa?](https://superuser.com/q/37910/24500)

[Symbolic links and 7zip](https://superuser.com/q/128969/24500)

---

I'm thinking we might as well throw in all the "How do I make a hard/soft link" questions into this list also.

[hardlinks on ntfs with windows](https://superuser.com/q/141784/24500)

[Make a hard link without extra programs in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/255731/24500)

---

**This question refers to Shortcuts**: [What is the difference between Symbolic Link and Shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/253935/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-link-and-shortcut)

We can probably just merge something about shortcuts into grawity's nicely formatted answer.

I have no idea how to tag this.

Comment: There's also the topic where you argued that NTFS hard links work for directories. It's not one of those you linked to. Any idea what that was about?

Comment: I admit, this is a very incomplete list. This is just the ones I've found from clicking on the right hand side.

Comment: OK, thought that was supposed to be all of them. Didn't realize this topic was than big.

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect candidate for a [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq) topic: *Everything you need to know about NTFS hard links, symbolic links, and junction points*.

Either wait for the topic to be part of [the canonical questions and answers drive](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3905/proposal-sponsoring-some-community-faqs-and-canonical-answers), or start your own [community-faq-proposed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq-proposed) topic, have a moderator make it *community wiki* and wait for answers to arrive. Maybe start a bounty after two days to get more attention.

---

I don't think we should outright *merge* them. They *aren't* the same question, after all. If the new topic is any good, let's revisit them after the community FAQ topic has been around for two weeks and close all questions it answers as duplicates.

Comment: IMO, they are all asking the same thing: either how to create such a link and to compare/contrast them. While grawity's answer isn't perfect, IMO it's the most comprehensive and we can later flesh it out to make it more friendly to read.  The only problem I have with making these answers longer is there is no way to create html anchors in the answer and thus provide a table of contents.  Maybe if one person posts multiple answers that makes sense, but that relies on the TOC post being the accepted answer.

Comment: @surfasb: I've fleshed out grawity's answer more as I agree it is quite comprehensive. It now really explains well *how* to do it, now we only need to add information (one or two paragraphs) to each section about *what* it is and *why* or *when* it is useful.