# Journeyman Geek's Monthly Bounty Hunt: July/August

Tags: discussion, bounty-hunt

I'm ploughing back some of my rep into the community, and hopefully getting some good/better answers up for questions. I really wouldn't be able to chase down *all* the worthy candidates for such a thing, so I'd like people to suggest questions that might do with a bounty.

Post the questions you think should get the bounty and why

A few ground rules in place to avoid drama... I'll post these every monthly bounty hunt, and change these as needed.

- I'd like to avoid self answers - if you can answer the question, you should do it without a bounty to encourage you.
- You can recommend any question, not just your own.
- ***Selection of a question is at my discretion***. I'll be awarding a minimum of 50 rep per month. If i can't find anything i like, that 50 rep gets rolled over to the next month. I may pick more questions or give more rep to an answer if i choose to. I suppose my offered bounty tab may be a guideline, but I don't ONLY do hardware questions
- Questions should be bountiable, and should be worth bountying. This means older questions with no answers, or ones where i can be convinced a bounty will get a quality answer. I'd like stuff that could do with a good, canonical answer.

I'll check back at this post - I'll pick the first question around the Last week of July, and pick one to give a bounty for. I'll also edit and update this question once thats done.

Comment: "first week of april"?

Comment: Fixed. Was gonna do it in august, then changed my mind and thought July, and then... The minions reponsible have been taken out back and shot ;p

Comment: Just yesterday I was asking what happened with the [community wiki sponsoring](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3905/proposal-sponsoring-some-community-faqs-and-canonical-answers) idea. Great to see you're trying to do something similar. Looking forward to the results. I also have a few rep points I don't absolutely need.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek good minions are so hard to come by these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Is it possible to remove the fade effect between login?](https://superuser.com/questions/451221/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-fade-effect-between-login)

Seems like a decent enough question to throw a bounty on. Note that there's a linked duplicate which says "nyah, nyah not possible."

Comment: And we have a winner by default. I'll post a request for suggestions for next month's MBH soon.