# Three batches of questions to close or delete

Tags: discussion

In line with [Help us clean up Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3158/help-us-clean-up-super-user), I've been closing a lot of questions recently, but some are fairly old and hard to get close votes on. Ideally I'd vote to delete but I don't have enough reputation, and I think the moderators are probably tired of my flagging!

Please look through the list of questions below and vote to close any you agree with.

**Batch 1**

All closed - see list below.

**Batch 2**

[All closed - scroll down to see the list](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3505/big-batch-of-questions-to-close-or-delete/3506#3506).

**Batch 3**

[All closed - scroll down to see the list](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3505/big-batch-of-questions-to-close-or-delete/3522#3522).

---

#### Batch 1: now closed or deleted

- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/27401/the-best-way-to-use-a-search-engine</s>
- <s>[How do you deal with spam when using a catch-all email address?](https://superuser.com/questions/21447/how-do-you-deal-with-spam-when-using-a-catch-all-email-address)</s>
- <s>[What do you remove from a default Mac OS X install?](https://superuser.com/questions/6831/what-do-you-remove-from-a-default-mac-os-x-install)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/8236/what-online-troubleshooting-tools-do-you-use-on-a-daily-basis</s>
- <s>[What third-party utilities do you have in your System Preferences "Other" section?](https://superuser.com/questions/17332/what-third-party-utilities-do-you-have-in-your-system-preferences-other-section)</s>
- <s>[Good printer review websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/45066/good-printer-review-websites)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/12740/free-icon-sets-for-websites</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/18623/what-is-the-most-notable-end-user-explanation-as-to-why-their-computer-is-broken</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/12964/anyone-know-how-to-cure-headache-and-nausea-from-laptop-viewing</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/16398/best-online-storage</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/2469/which-subscription-music-service-do-you-use</s>
- <s>[Which web services should be integrated?](https://superuser.com/questions/16608/which-web-services-should-be-integrated)</s>
- <s>[Firefox add-ons with a rich look and feel](https://superuser.com/questions/12130/firefox-add-ons-with-a-rich-look-and-feel)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/12225/is-it-ethical-to-spoof-registration-forms-on-websites</s>
- <s>[Whats the next desktop application you would like to see moved to the web?](https://superuser.com/questions/10352/whats-the-next-desktop-application-you-would-like-to-see-moved-to-the-web)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/6494/what-is-your-favorite-windows-annoyance-buster</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/3446/what-are-the-must-listen-to-general-technology-podcasts</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/78/what-single-site-resource-do-you-use-to-keep-up-with-pc-hardware</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/1288/must-have-thunderbird-addons</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/2186/which-twitter-app-do-you-use</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/2598/online-meetings-any-recommendations</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/474/what-feature-do-you-like-most-from-windows</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/10623/what-does-your-workspace-setup-look-like-pictures</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/12526/what-woud-be-the-ideal-iphone-application-that-does-not-exist-today</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/2610/best-twitter-client-for-linux</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/3498/what-experiences-have-you-had-with-your-tethered-smartphone</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/253/which-productive-keyboard-would-you-recommend</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/10838/what-is-your-favorite-widget-or-gadget</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/10846/what-is-your-favorite-platform-for-widgets-or-gadgets</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/20869/has-anyone-customised-their-text-editor-in-a-way-that-is-unique-to-them</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/20972/what-else-do-linux-distros-need-in-order-attract-the-non-geek-user-groups</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/21035/web-sites-for-windows-mobile-software</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/21268/horror-stories-of-building-a-system</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/21387/what-printer-has-the-best-ink-to-cost-ratio</s>
- <s>[Any coolosxapps.net alternative? (New OS X Software Blog)](https://superuser.com/questions/29091/any-coolosxapps-net-alternative-new-os-x-software-blog)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/22113/good-workout-web-app</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/29338/which-operating-system-is-good-for-which-user</s>
- <s>[What interesting uses for IPv6 are out there?](https://superuser.com/questions/29606/what-interesting-uses-for-ipv6-are-out-there)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/30398/fun-projects-to-do-with-an-old-17-lcd-monitor</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/22570/which-linux-install-should-you-start-with</s>

Comment: Not sure the Windows 7 features and catch-all spam topics are that bad. Voted on the rest.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I proposed the spam one because it seemed to be outside the obvious realm of software/hardware, but I could be wrong. The Windows 7 question does involve facts, but I felt it's difficult to have a direct (accepted) answer there.

Comment: Been through and added my close votes to those I thought deserved it.

Comment: Is it schizophrenic to both vote to close a question and add it to favorites?

Comment: Some *are* interesting or funny to read through. But of much value, I don't know ...

Comment: personally, I'd leave the Windows 7 features & the note taking tool questions - those have value.  The others, good work crew!

Comment: Thanks! I'll remove those two from the list. I'll have another batch to post up later today as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

#### Batch 2: now closed or deleted

- <s>[what's your favourite bookmark utility similar to google's bookmark](https://superuser.com/questions/97519/whats-your-favourite-bookmark-utility-similar-to-googles-bookmark)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/72571/registering-domain-names-with-non-ascii-characters-on-them</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/21155/best-quicksilver-clone-on-windows</s>
- <s>[What are your favourite free fonts?](https://superuser.com/questions/40045/what-are-your-favourite-free-fonts)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/3391/which-hidden-feature-plugin-of-notepad-is-the-most-important-productivity-boost</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/11383/what-are-the-best-virtualdub-addons</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/22703/free-image-sources-for-photo-mosaics</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/95216/what-is-your-favorite-bbs-forum-system</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/52070/buying-bulk-domain-names-any-tips</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/49835/why-should-we-use-web-app-over-google-docs</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/49138/email-etiquette-thank-you-reply</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/47355/what-online-music-store-do-you-use</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/46030/list-of-tiny-portable-free-apps-that-you-use</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/39986/what-is-the-best-bluetooth-keyboard-for-windows-mobile</s>
- <s>[Where do spammers get their info?](https://superuser.com/questions/31559/where-do-spammers-get-their-info)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/22506/what-does-ie-do-better-than-other-browsers</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/31675/best-software-on-your-companys-intranet</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/33871/is-an-apple-monitor-worth-the-cost</s>
- <s>[Software Review Questions](https://superuser.com/questions/34295/software-review-questions)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/39869/looking-for-websites-to-download-free-software</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/46903/downloading-movies-with-bit-torrent</s>
- <s>[What is the best GNU screen "taskbar" you've used/seen?](https://superuser.com/questions/51988/what-is-the-best-gnu-screen-taskbar-youve-used-seen)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/168656/favorite-and-useful-firefox-aboutconfig-tweaks</s>
- <s>[Microsoft Outlook tips and tricks for improving user experience?](https://superuser.com/questions/31996/microsoft-outlook-tips-and-tricks-for-improving-user-experience)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/34805/remote-desktop-tips-and-tricks</s>

Comment: Prompted me to ask [this question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3510/recommendations-for-the-best).

Comment: You forgot to vote on the photo mosaics.

Comment: @Daniel I caught it later on but unfortunately was already out of close votes for today!

Comment: Added my close votes (and cast the final binding vote on a few as well, MUAHAHA. **cough**).

Answer (score 2):

#### Batch 3: now closed or deleted

- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/261330/firefox-4-0-tips-and-tricks</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/141933/best-facebook-client-for-windows</s>
- <s>[Receiving more email than I can handle](https://superuser.com/questions/176334/receiving-more-email-than-i-can-handle)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/177047/how-to-power-use-microsoft-outlook</s>
- <s>[Most useful automated tasks?](https://superuser.com/questions/175677/most-useful-automated-tasks)</s>
- <s>[How do you organize your partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/159944/how-do-you-organize-your-partitions)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/149055/what-are-your-favorite-netcat-tricks</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/145329/windows-live-writer-code-snippets-plugins</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/144800/which-terminal-emulator-do-you-use-why</s>
- <s>[Best SSD tweaks for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/137817/best-ssd-tweaks-for-windows-7)</s>
- <s>[The best lightweight window manager for linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/12145/the-best-lightweight-window-manager-for-linux)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/132255/saving-music-wisely-why-save-queen-bohemian-rhapsody-mp3-millions-of-times</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/64602/when-is-the-best-time-to-purchase-a-new-computer</s>
- <s>[What are your most useful textexpander (or similar) snippets?](https://superuser.com/questions/120301/what-are-your-most-useful-textexpander-or-similar-snippets)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/105642/which-is-best-to-use-norton-or-windows-back-up</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/105068/common-reasons-not-to-use-openoffice</s>
- <s>[Which is best as a headless server? Ubuntu, Solaris, FreeBSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/105514/which-is-best-as-a-headless-server-ubuntu-solaris-freebsd)</s>
- <s>[Tips for improving Windows 7 performance on a netbook](https://superuser.com/questions/99580/tips-for-improving-windows-7-performance-on-a-netbook)</s>
- <s>[Good forums about hacking/computer security issues](https://superuser.com/questions/99352/good-forums-about-hacking-computer-security-issues)</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/94035/what-is-a-good-source-of-information-regarding-openid-why-should-i-use-it</s>
- <s>https://superuser.com/questions/71240/copyright-issues-in-online-storage</s>
- <s>[Simple flatbed scanner - but it must work in Windows 7 Prof x64 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/86804/simple-flatbed-scanner-but-it-must-work-in-windows-7-prof-x64)</s>
- <s>[What are some of the better Windows 7 Themes?](https://superuser.com/questions/86359/what-are-some-of-the-better-windows-7-themes)</s>

Comment: Now that was quick!

Comment: Had some time on my hands this morning and cleaned these up

Comment: Nice, thanks for doing that!

Comment: But @Diago... didn't you get the memo? You're an exception handler!

Comment: @Daniel. I was bored.