# is this question off topic

Tags: support, off-topic

I recently asked https://superuser.com/questions/650929/tool-software-to-surprise-during-birthday on Super User. Will the question would be off topic? I have mentioned my problem clear. Normal search on search engines doesn't helped me, so posted as an question over here.

Will the question would be off topic?

Comment: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372) [Since when are software recommendations off-topic?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3515)

Comment: @Sathya i have mentioned my problem clear,from that answer **ask about your problem instead**. i have mentioned my problem and asked solution..normal search engines doesnt helped and i have mentioned it over there too

Comment: read the linked question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your question is off-topic. The reason *why* it is off-topic is displayed below your question.

In cases like these, it would make sense to **edit** your question to make it less about a simple product recommendation and more about the *process* of achieving your goal.

A *better* question to ask would be **How can I trigger a certain program when the computer starts up on a given date?** Which is essentially what you want to do.

You should tag your question with [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) to make it clear that you want to learn about the process for both operating systems.