# Why was my software-rec question closed?

Tags: support

How is [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/402991/software-to-track-things-ive-read-watched-and-played) worse than, for example, [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/127503/any-software-to-keep-track-of-my-reading-progress)?

I believe I have provided a fairly comprehensive list of requirements, so that a best answer would be possible. Of the 10 requirements I've noted, only 2 could be considered subjective (History of privacy-consciousness and inoffensive interface).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with what @[random](https://meta.superuser.com/users/307/random) has to say, it is worth nothing that **what we consider acceptable has changed over the past few years.** What you gave us is dated back to 2010, when it was fine. That was 2 years ago. We no longer accept such questions as being on topic.

You are very welcome to ask us for help and shopping questions in the Chat. Our room is [Root Access.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/%5C)

Comment: I see, guess I should've paid more attention when searching. Doubt the 2 people who will be exposed to my question at Root Access will have an answer, though.

Comment: @kotekzot The question will be there for a bit, and anyone who joins can see it.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't any worse, but now that you've found one that has slipped through the cracks, that too has been closed.

These ["I have a list of specs, fill my hole of desire"](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4383/why-is-looking-for-alternative-programs-not-constructive) type questions beg for a list or for everyone to throw in a suggestion of what might fit.

They are, without a price tag, shopping questions.

It is better for you and others in future to just try something and then see where it comes up short. Then, ask the community for help in getting the product to do what you think it may be failing on. If they so then happen to suggest another program entirely, so be it.

Comment: Everything I've found comes up short, as the only program that tracks more than 1 type of creative works (Booxter) runs on Mac OS exclusively and doesn't do games. I doubt framing my question with Booxter would improve it in any way.