# I have a suggestion on what to do with the Software Rec Tag

Tags: discussion, questions, superuser-blog, software-rec

With the upcoming release of Windows 8 we expect an influx of users and questions.  I feel that we need to prep for their coming.  With that in mind, the [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) is a nuisance in [mine](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2090/47225) and [others](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3518/47225) [opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  I believe that the general consensus of this tag is that **anything** that is of a [recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) nature needs to be closed and stopped.

### BUT!!!

The community wants/needs it's software recommendations.  We like them, and we even [promote good free ones](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012).  So how do we continue to offer suggestions to users regarding software, and yet keep the site uncluttered from off-topic questions?

My solution is two fold:

1. **Teach a Man to fish** - I'm not talking about stepping into the [trap of help vampires](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem), but rather make sure the resources are there for new users to read, and verteran users to reference when enforcing the rules.  These included (but are not limited to):

   - Updating the FAQ to state that software/hardware recommendations are NOT allowed.
   - Create [a Meta Post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) on how to recommend a piece of software to questions whose solution require software.
   - Create [a Meta Post](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/47225) on how to ask questions that *may* require software to be recommended
2. **The Super User Recommendation Blog entries!** - I suggest we create blog entries that can be updated as needed on common software that Super User's use/suggest.  This would be similar to what [LifeHacker does](http://lifehacker.com/apps/) with their software recommendations.  If this is instituted then I suggest the following actions:

   - Close ALL posts that are off-topic and remove the [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) tag.
   - Port over any worthwhile questions/answers to the blog.
   - When cleaned up, they can be burninated forever.

By closing all posts as soon as possible, we don't get any confusion like this:

[Why was my software-rec question closed?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4622/why-was-my-software-rec-question-closed)

and allows us time to port over things to the blog at a pace that is doable.  This also gives us a *heavily moderated* medium to recommend software without being closed all the time.

Comment: Hear hear. Note that a while ago (can't find the link), it was suggested to move the results of our polling questions to tag wikis, but making blog entries would sound like a better idea, since it's moved to the public. We could start by looking at the most popular questions…

Comment: meh, I'm not too keen about porting to blog. By the time the entries have been moved, the software is likely to be outdated. Editing post themselves are hard enough, I fear the blog entries will gather dust even more.

Comment: @Sathya we don't have to port everything just ones that seem worthwhile.

Comment: @KronoS: What would be considered worthwhile? Pushing only software recommendations to the blog can be a pain, it could sink the blog in posts that are continuously of the same type. Tag wikis are in that view a better place, but sadly people don't look there often. Yet, I don't feel like publicizing it necessarily is a better idea. I think it's more worthwhile building up an actual software recommendation site next to Super User than trying to move them into a place they don't belong. Putting that aside, the problem is that users don't search enough for software. Are they able to find it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could we finally get rid of \[software-rec\]?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8505/could-we-finally-get-rid-of-software-rec)