# Is this site not partly about uncommon specific software solutions?

Tags: support

My question was in regards to asking for a solution that takes up a cumulative hour or so of my time every-single-day . I am now able to do this in a fraction of the time, thanks to my question. (yeah, I tend to close photoshop because my work computer is slow and I need too many things open at once)

The Rules:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
> question about …
>
> computer hardware **computer software** personal and home computer
> networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> videogames or consoles websites or web services like Facebook,
> Twitter, and WordPress electronic devices, media players, cell phones
> or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> issues specific to corporate IT support and networks a shopping or
> buying recommendation

My Question:

[Low profile On-Screen Color Grabber? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/486988/low-profile-on-screen-color-grabber)

> I'm looking for a program that will allow me to grab colors from on
> screen, something that won't bother me or effect performance if it's
> running constantly in the background.
>
> What this is for: is replacing my need to take a screenshot, put it in
> photoshop, and grab the hex color that way. I do this about 10 times a
> day, every day due to the nature of my work.
>
> I know there is a solution out there for me, but I'm not able to find
> anything even remotely similar to what I'm wanting.

How exactly is this off-topic? Granted my title was bad, I'm terrible at making good titles, but the question was sound and on-topic as far as what the rules say.

Thankfully I was allowed to choose a best answer and get a good answer before this was closed.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software

Comment: @OliverSalzburg so... it was the way I asked the question? That's silly, but thanks for the link.

Comment: I just wanted to mention the question as I was sure it was relevant to your question. I didn't have time to properly judge the matter yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say you've already found something that didn't suit your needs, tell us what that was. That way, you probably won't end up getting the same suggestions over and over again. But even then, I'm not convinced a simple search for color picker software for Windows wouldn't have given you the same result.

Basically, we don't encourage these kinds of "recommend me software" questions that don't show research effort — not claiming you didn't do any, you even said you looked, but what have you found and why didn't it work for you? — or aren't narrow enough.

To give an example of what we want to avoid: [color picker utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192498/color-picker-utility).

In the future, if you're looking for something that may (or may not) be solved with a specific application, just ask for your real problem, not the software to solve it. For example, you have this cumbersome solution of opening up Photoshop, but want a faster alternative, and you've already found *X*, which doesn't work because of *Foo*, and *Y*, which doesn't work because of *Bar*.

Comment: I have searched quite a few times over the course of several months, but couldn't find the one that was linked (or anything else that would suit my needs). I figured the solution would be bundled in with some other utility software that did something else. Either way, thanks for clearing it up.