# Question was closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Why was this closed? This seems like it matches the Q&A format.

> [What can I use to track application internet usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/501797/what-can-i-use-to-track-application-internet-usage)

Comment: Not to mention that this question is a dupe of probably a dozen similar questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for a product to do such and such is usually considered open ended, non constructive, and off topic. We like questions that can have one REALLY GOOD answer (that you would mark as the definitive answer), with other answers that may help other users.

To get around this, try asking for a process, as opposed to an actual product or software that would accomplish xx.

Comment: "To get around this, try asking for a process, as opposed to an actual product or software that would accomplish xx."
Ah, this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you're already asking for a program. This sets off alarms for most people, as it hints at a "product recommendation".

Luke already explained the core issue with those types of questions. Please see [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) for the full details.

The key is to ask for a solution, not a product. The solution can make use of a product, but the product in itself is never the solution.