# Software recommendations - what software can do this

Tags: support

Is all types of software recommendation questions off topic; I appreciate it's probably not a 100% fixed rule and that some questions need to be taken as is, but, if the questions was:

"What software allows me perform a specific function (eg search for text only within .txt files)"

Would this be considered off topic (if this was the entire question)?

Comment: Related: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software)

Comment: Thank you Bob, this is also really good info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Focus on the problem and leave out the software and it ought to be fine.

"I'm trying to search for specific text fields in a directory, but only in .txt files - I've tried the following approaches (blah blah blah) but they had these specific problems (blah blah blah). I'm looking for an outcome thats like (foo bar baz). How would I do this?" should work I think

Comment: Should I recommend Dave software that does what he asks about?

Comment: Well, if you include an explaination of how to do it, with instructions, heck yes, I'd upvote that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think this answers it for me  :)