# I'd like to know why my question was closed

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-request, close-reasons, off-topic

I posted a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/525729/issues-with-file-history-looking-for-alternative) detailing my problems with Windows 8's File History. I use it for backups and I have a couple of things I'd like it to do, but it fell short. With certain specific needs in mind, I asked if there are any pieces of software that might match my requirements.

I've looked into the [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/19459) thread before posting on meta. In my original post I had tried being specific with the requirements I had for my backup software and tried avoiding subjective terms, so I have trouble seeing why my question was closed.

Could you elaborate on why my question was rejected, despite my belief that I acted in accordance with community rules? Is there a way that I can improve the post so that it may be reopened?

Comment: As I [mentioned on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7462567#7462567), if you focus on *what problems you have* with File History. You haven't really detailed them, and there might very well be solutions to the problems you're facing. If users happen to suggest using an alternative instead, that's also okay. As for show us *what you've already tried* as an alternative (and why that didn't work out), this is usually better than merely asking for alternatives.

Comment: That being said, I'd be inclined to reopen if you could give us more details on the problems, and if you just tried Acronis, which you do mention but dismiss because "the reviews are horrible". The tool has a trial version IIRC.

Comment: *You haven't really detailed [what problems you have with File History]* I assume you're referring to the first three bullet points in my post. What kind of information could I add to "it's not showing a progress bar" or "automatic backup doesn't kick in 2 hours after the NAS has been turned on"? Do I need to analyze some kind of log files and paste the results, for example? I'm unsure what other things I can try to solve the File History problem.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, so I can't specifically help you with that, sorry. Just some general pointers. I'm sure someone will know what to look for.

Comment: *and if you just tried Acronis, which you do mention but dismiss because "the reviews are horrible"* True, I didn't try it myself. But according to several people on [this page](http://www.amazon.com/Acronis-TI-16-DV-RT-W-EN-True-Image-2013/dp/B0095C25Y8/) it is ridden with bugs that have been around since the 2012 version involving crucial stuff like unrecoverable images. Even if I don't trigger such bugs in a small-scale test, they might pop up when it's too late. My time is limited and I cannot run extensive tests with every backup program I find; that's why I relied on the reviews.

Comment: `Do you know any File History alternatives that fit these requirements?` --> There are tons of incremental back-up solutions out there, you can try quite a few of them and tell us why they don't work; in its current state any incremental back-up solution can be suggested which is why it doesn't fit well as a question, to put it otherwise software recommendation questions should yield only a very small number of solutions specific to a certain problem.

Comment: *There are tons of incremental back-up solutions out there* Are they \*continuous\* incremental back-up solutions though? Perhaps my Google skills aren't up to snuff, but I'm having trouble figuring out what other people are using for these tasks. Most of the stuff I've uncovered myself isn't continuous and/or is hard to use. Command-line stuff like `rsync` just isn't gonna cut it for me.