# How can I ask for a program?

Tags: discussion, support

Occasionally I like to ask questions about programs that has the features I´am asking for.
Sometime ago I did a questions like that:

[Looking for a program that stores images from the clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/536287/looking-for-a-program-that-stores-the-images-from-the-clipboard)

But some people put me -2 in votes.
I wonder "why?"

should´n do questions like that?
I think this kind of questions are very usefull when you are looking for a program with a set of certain features.
I think is a smart way to looking for a program, you know...you think what you need, you describe it and someone, probably, has seen anything like that and wants to share with you the name of the program.

So my question is:

**Can I make questions like I described before? like a certain program that does a certain thing**

I think It´s correct, because if there are a lot o programs with a set of certain features, that´s not mean it is a open question I want just one, I can close my own question but in the good way, I mean I close my own questions by accepting any of the  answers that have been given to me. 
I think that the bad way for closing questions is when a third person decides to close your question.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: See: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) – basically, asking whether there's an app that does this and that still often ends up in a list of answers, as your question has demonstrated. Note that just because you accepted an answer this doesn't mean your question is closed—it'll still attract answers that are basically just links to some software. Not really the kind of question we're aiming for, unfortunately.

Comment: See the new (still in Beta) site at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Software Suggestions - it is getting off to a very good start. Be sure to read the guidelines, though. Don't just ask "what's the best program to XXX?", describe your requirements in as much detail as you can in order to help others to help you