# Can you please review my ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have been banned from asking questions.  I went through the post at [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998)

My account does not come in any of those sections.

There is no other I can find out why I have been banned.  Can some one please explain?

I have made one answer and it **has** helped the user.  It solved some ones problem, yet I am supposed to be a mis-fit as per some people in your team or your algorithm.  Would like to know why.  Please dont redirect me to the post you made, I went through it and I have done nothing wrong.  If you can prove I have done, then please post it here, else please apologize.

Comment: Note that *question ban* and *answer ban* are separate, and it's likely the quality of your answer does not factor into the question ban criteria (or not enough to offset what slhck explained)

Comment: Thanks for specifying.  The way I thought I can prove that I am useful - is by adding a good answer.  Now I dont know what else I can do.

Answer (score 10):

Of the six questions you've asked until now

- four have been closed
- three are now deleted
- none have received a single upvote

It seems the ban is working as intended, as there seems to have been no increase in the quality of your questions over time.

I believe having https://superuser.com/questions/547059/is-there-windows-logging-software-that-can-tell-me-what-all-i-have-done-on-the-p fixed and reopened would be the best way to overcome the ban. You deleted the question, but having deleted questions is never good when you're banned.

At the moment it is not showing any research (e.g. what logging tools you may have found that don't provide what you need), and might be a little too broad with a list for requirements. You could definitely edit it and have  a moderator review it. For more specific guidance on what  to do, feel free to ask on Meta or regulars on [chat](http://chat.superuser.com/).

Comment: All the questions were long back, atleast 6 months back.  Now I know how to ask a question.  Does your ban logic keep me away from asking a question until eternity?   Is that the way your ban-logic works?

Comment: The algorithm behind the ban is not known. However, providing useful answers *should* help get your account back into good standing. Improving your existing posts is also encouraged, if possible. I've undeleted one question [you had deleted yourself](http://superuser.com/questions/547059/is-there-windows-logging-software-that-can-tell-me-what-all-i-have-done-on-the-p), which should help, but this is as much as we can do for you.

Comment: There are 4 questions I can see on my profile now :
The 3 below have no down votes and are not bad questions I understand
How to make a software use .mov decoder?
How to get the timestamp (and location stamp) with a key press?
How can I change the System Manufacturer as displayed by System Information? [duplicate]

The fourth one is a bad question and has one down vote, and that is why I had deleted it all together (which you have undeleted)
Is there Windows logging software that can tell me what all I have done on the PC so far? [closed]

Comment: What should be next step? Should I fix the question "Is there Windows logging software that can tell me what all I have done on the PC so far?"?  Will that help me be un-banned?

Comment: The community tends to vote to close questions that ask for software, such as this one. You might want to focus more on what specific problem you have with what Windows' logging feature already offers, and then ask how to achieve what you need. Maybe you could narrow your question down a bit, not asking for one tool that does everything, but about specific things you need. If you want more specific advice you could come to [chat] as well.

Comment: I did not know I was not supposed to ask for softwares.  I relaized that from the comments.  So, I went ahead and created a batch script myself which did the logging.  I used windows commands to build my own logging system.  So, that issue is solved for me now.  So, should I again fix that question? Or can I just delete it?

Comment: Also : Can you please review my questions and tell me if you really feel the user should be banned? Are they really that bad?

Comment: No, please don't delete it. That would make your ban worse. You should edit the question to improve it, and if you have an answer—even better! I'd reopen the question for you, so you can answer it yourself. I think in your case the ban is a little borderline, but improving that one question should get you back on track, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for telling me not to delete.  The only thing I feel is wrong with my question is the last line "Do you know any such tool? Or some thing close? Paid or free?"  Rest of the content tries to explain what I need.  So, if you open it again, I will be deleting that last line.  Is that what is expected?  Or is there something more I need to learn?

Comment: I think its okay, please dont take any efforts for me.   I personally do not feel the system helps ask good questions.  I dont know why asking for a software in this case is bad.  Basically I needed a command that would give me this data.  There is no other way I could have asked the question.  I could have changed the question just for the sake of changing.  
I feel I am better off elsewhere.  Thanks for your very very prompt responses.  Regards.  Bye.

Comment: Also, in case you need to verify if I habitually ask bad questions - you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881114/need-algorithm-and-implementation-help-compare-2-files which is also a question I have asked.

Comment: There are many discussions here on Meta about the topic of software recommendation questions and why they're not welcome. I agree it sometimes takes a while to get to know what questions are acceptable and which ones aren't—that however shouldn't drive you away. I *think* there's a way to salvage that question of yours, but it's just a little too broad right now.

Comment: @user1744649 if you're having a hard time asking questions about software I recommend [reading this post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/47225).