# Request to reopen question 600238

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request, off-topic

[This question about creating CD+Gs from MP4s](https://superuser.com/questions/600238/how-do-i-make-cdgs-from-mp4s) was closed this morning, 27 May 2013, at 04:05 UTC for being off-topic: in its original form, the question was obviously a software-rec.

Twelve minutes later, at 04:17, my [suggested edit to the question](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/115198), which rephrased it so that it didn't explicitly ask for software, was approved.

Since it's been edited to be less software-reccy, I'd appreciate a second look at it to see if it could be reopened.

Comment: Question looks reasonable enough now.

Comment: @DanielBeck so are software-rec tagged questions sort-of inherently off-topic on superuser?

Comment: @TeXnewbie ya pretty much.  If you're asking for a software recommendation then it'll be closed.  However you can kinda get around it by [asking your question this way](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/47225).