# Why this question is closed as off-topic?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question

I know the what questions are [on topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), but I fail to understand, why [asking about pdf-viewing](https://superuser.com/questions/605668/is-there-pdf-reader-for-linux-that-allows-to-zoom-to-the-actual-text-skiping-th/605670) has fallen out? I did not ask about shopping recommendation.

I express disappointment that 5 people did close my question, and no one cared to explain why.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, and programs are considered products. Your question can easily be reworded though (e.g. "I want to read ebooks without the page borders showing"), so you could try that.

Comment: @DanielBeck I understand. But that's silly, isn't it? The rewording doesn't change the actual meaning, just the vocabulary I use (to avoid words like "program" or "reader")

Comment: OK. I basically changed "PDF reader" -> "way to read PDF files".

Comment: [Here's our general guide on how to ask questions like this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software). FWIW I don't understand it either. I wouldn't have closed it, because the actual problem, or goal, of your question is pretty obvious.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. Do you think I should re-post the question again with the proper wording, or just leave it closed as it is now?

Comment: *Originally* this question did appear to be a software recommendation to me; however, even in it's current form, you're unlikely to get any constructive answers (the answer depends on a particular program supporting this to begin with).  I think [the single answer you have now](http://superuser.com/a/605670/6887) is as good as it's going to get.  Why can't you just manually zoom in and lock/prevent horizontal scrolling?  Most PDF viewers should restore your position/zoom for a document when re-opening the file, so this should only have to be done once per PDF...

Comment: @Breakthrough I'm afraid it is not that easy. Many ebooks have different margins for odd and even pages. And even then, for someone who reads tons of different PDFs, manually adjusting the zoom isn't really a good option.

Comment: @Breakthrough By this logic one should close every question, once it gets a single accepted answer.

Comment: @Breakthrough If there is no automated way to zoom into the actual text in PDF, it is still a valid answer for me. On the other hand, since this simple Onyx Boox thing I have is partly open source, I though that maybe its functionality made it through to the PC world already.

Comment: `By this logic one should close every question, once it gets a single accepted answer` is a gross oversimplification of what I said.  I was just pointing out the relatively obscurity of this feature (at least relative to the desktop market, as if that wasn't the case you'd have no reason to ask this in the first place), and that it's unlikely you'll find any answers outside of modifying a PDF viewer or the PDF's themselves.  Search as I might, I can only find references to this "feature" in Android software - thus my comments...

Comment: @Breakthrough Thank you. What you have just written is partly a valid answer to my question. (I still find it a little rude that you and few other people preferred to close the question instead of telling me just what you have written.)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski - The reason we didn't is because thats what Meta or the chatroom is for.  Discussions should take place through comments.  Its not about being rude, the original version of the question, was improved upon.  Besides the question is now open.

Comment: This is an aside, but any time you edit a closed question within 5 days of it being closed, it automatically goes into the Reopen Review Queue, where any user with >3000 rep can choose to vote to reopen it.

Comment: @nhinkle I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question has been reopened now.