# Are questions about recommending plug ins or add on off topic?

Tags: support

I know software recommendations are off topic and to me, an add on / plug in is software but, not sure if that is true for all?

For example, "please recommend a plug in / add on for Chrome so I can do...."

Can some one confirm if this is on or off topic? Is it actually software recommendations are off topic or product recommendations are off topic (may be they mean the same thing but we all have different interpretations)?

Comment: Couldn't you just phrase it as "I want to X in Chrome, how can I do that?" [There might be surprisingly easy solutions](http://superuser.com/questions/296575/google-chrome-extension-that-highlights-all-links-on-a-webpage). [This recommendation applies here as well](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software).

Comment: Again, thank you @DanielBeck for the quick response. I'm sure you could, but I'm not asking this question just curious if this falls under 'software recommendation'.

Comment: I think the point that DanielBeck was going for is that any question that asks "Please recommend <insert subject here> that does <X action here>" is off-topic for Super User.  As long as you follow the recommendations of how to ask questions, questions regarding plug-ins/add-ons are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I know a software recommendation is considered off-topic but sometimes specifying a software tool or a workflow is all you need to do. If you can formulate your question specifying a software tool or a workflow (a "How to") instead of asking for software recommendation then your likely not to have your question closed.