# Re-opening my question on ebook managment tools

Tags: support, status-completed

My question: [Ebook management: how to catalog/access files in their original location](https://superuser.com/questions/372263/ebook-management-how-to-catalog-access-files-in-their-original-location)
I believe my question can be reopened with probably some minor modifications.

Comment: You've only changed the title of the question. You're still asking about a specific product. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software

Comment: @OliverSalzburg so what should be done? Are you going to close every single question on the site that mentions a product name?

Comment: Also, the product mention is relevant for the context: I'm seeking to address a specific weakness that is not addressed by it.

Comment: You're missing the point. If you want to ask me if I'm going to close any question on the site that doesn't comply with the rules set forth by our community, then the answer is yes. Mentioning a product name is irrelevant in this context. The problem with your question is explained in the meta post I mentioned in my initial comment.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I think you are the one who is missing the point, my question is motivated by a specific but not at all uncommon use case with a type of software, nobody is going to be fooled that this is not the case even if I make ludicrous attempts to hide it. If you are only concerned with semantics, then say so.

Answer (score 5):

I have edited your question and voted to reopen.  This is a one time deal to show you how to edit the question to better match what we're looking for here.  Please review the meta post that Oliver pointed out.

Also, I don't really appreciate the tone that you've taken up with him.  Oliver is trying his best to be helpful to you and the site.  Treating him with angst and derision is not going to make you very many friends here.  He makes some very good points and I stand behind his actions/words.