# Why offtopic and if truly offtopic then where to ask it? http://superuser.com/questions/610759

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked this question [How to determine whether audio is music or not](https://superuser.com/questions/610759)

I have read https://superuser.com/help/on-topic and I am baffled as to why was it put on hold and later closed as OFFTOPIC by not only one but FIVE moderators!

I have later rephrased eliminating all the intro as to why would I want to achieve what I ask but I see no change.
I can't post link to original phrasing but I'm sure you masters of superuser have access to that.
If somebody kind enough cares to explain why was it offtopic I would deeply appreciate also to name another place where it would be appropriate to ask it.
Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't closed by Moderators, but community members. You're asking for software recommendation, which http://superuser.com/help/on-topic mentions are offtopic. _asking for a shopping or product recommendation_. See also: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372)

Comment: what if I say "my brain can detect whether a sound stream is music or not. how can I detect music from an audio clip using a computer instead of my brain", whould it still get offtopic?  

how should I phrase this and where should I ask that if not superuser?!

Comment: does this comply with rules and suggestions?: "I would like to listen to talkshows and newsreports from a certain radio station but not to their music.  

My brain can detect whether a temporally delimited sound stream is music or not, so when an annoying song begins playing on that radio station, I turn the volume off then after 3-4 minutes I turn it up again.

How can I make use of a PC instead of brain to perform the same action? I googled but found no solutions yet, therefore I'm turning to you, Super-Users.
"

Comment: yes, that does seem fine - please edit the question

Comment: @Sathya thanks for the clarifications. Your comments have answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the question further to better match what is on-topic for here and voted to re-open the question.  Use it as a guide for further questions of this type.  You may also find this meta post useful:

[How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software)