# In what cases do I see a more elaborate off-topic close reason?

Tags: support, closed-questions, off-topic

In some cases, I see a newly extended off-topic post notice:

> ### closed as off-topic by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers
>
> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." - OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question or leave a comment.

However, in others, I see the original one since the closing overhaul:

> ### closed as off-topic by OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers
>
> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." - OneUser, TwoUsers, ThreeUsers, FourUsers, FiveUsers
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question or leave a comment.

In what cases is each one used?

Comment: Some links where you saw both?

Comment: @Sathya First case: http://superuser.com/questions/638846/surface-display-screen-stops-working-after-leaving-cover-on-for-a-long-time Second case: http://superuser.com/questions/699997/what-windows-should-i-upgrade-to-on-our-small-office-network-now-that-windows-xp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the more elaborate message when looking at your own questions. The intent here is to provide a little bit more context for the person who asked the question, in hope that it might help them to be more receptive to the specific off-topic reason that follows. There was some concern when the system was being designed that folks would fail to understand what "off-topic" meant, so this additional passage attempts to explain it.

Comment: This seems more plausible.

Comment: But why do I not see it when I am looking at someone else's question?

Comment: Because it's noisy and presumably less important when it's not your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I see different reasons from what you mention

[Surface display screen stops working after leaving cover on for a long time](https://superuser.com/questions/638846/surface-display-screen-stops-working-after-leaving-cover-on-for-a-long-time) has

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions about bugs in pre-release/beta software or prototype hardware are off-topic. Bugs in pre-release products are common and
>     even expected, and are often fixed before the final version is
>     released — at which point the question becomes obsolete. Consider
>     reporting these types of problems directly to the product
>     manufacturer." –

while

[What Windows should I upgrade to on our small office network now that Windows XP has reached the end of its supported lifecycle?](https://superuser.com/questions/699997/what-windows-should-i-upgrade-to-on-our-small-office-network-now-that-windows-xp) has

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and
>     attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and
>     the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. [Here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/)
>     [are a few suggestions](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/) on how to properly ask this type of question

both were closed with different off-topic reasons

[image]

and hence the different explanations were shown. The reason for "bugs in pre-release/beta software or prototype hardware" were withdrawn because we have a limited number of reason slots and this wasn't being used.

If the last reason is shown, then you'll get a generic "This question appears to be off-topic" reason, with the actual reason mentioned in the comment

Comment: Um, no. The "This question is not about..." reasons were just examples. On the first question, I see the longer message. I'm not sure why you see the shorter message. Can you email a developer and see what the correct answer is?

Comment: I mean, I can tell you a set of questions that have the same off-topic close reasons but different closure intros.

Comment: I don't see the longer message, either when logged in or incognito. Can you add a screenshot? I don't have access to developers' email addresses and even if I did, I wouldn't email them over this or anything for that matter. The community managers, would probably add a word or two about this.

Comment: A community manager answered this now.