# Can I ask for software recommendations?

Tags: discussion

I understand the need for questions to be concise, and with limited scope; however I'm looking for an answer the following type of question:

> Can someone recommend a piece of software that does (a) or (b). I have tested (x), (y), and (z) piece of software however they have the following issues and don't do exactly what I need.

- Is this an acceptable question?
- Is superuser a good place to ask the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these questions are explicitly off-topic on Super User. We have the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) for that now.

Comment: Or, if the problem you think requires a recommendation is **specific and well-researched**, [just ask for help solving the problem](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software). A good question on Software Recs is probably a good question here too, you just have to drop the "recommend me a software that..." facade. (Of course, by the same token a bad question on SR is a terrible question here, so...)

Comment: Make sure you first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) as they have strict rules about what information should be provided in your question.