# Why was my question closed as "off topic"?

Tags: support

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/1525880/hdd-certain-unrecoverable-read-failure-ure-after-12tb-read-true-or-false) was closed as off topic.

[image]

The only feedback was the boilerplate:

> Closed. This question is [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. [Here are a few suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/) on how to properly ask this type of question.

I addressed pointed out issues in a comment, but there was no reply. After I few edits of the question I flagged for moderator attention, but it was refused, again with no feedback.

The boilerplate links to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) where it says:

> If you have a question about … computer hardware … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

My question is about hard drives, which is computer hardware.

The boilerplate also says:

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic

My question is not seeking any recommendations.

The following text is about recommendations, if I understand correctly, so unrelated to my question, but I will (and already did in the comments of my question) address them:

- "become outdated quickly"
  My question is about a property of hard drives, that is as old as they (so roughly 30 years) and will be relevant as long as HDD (and similar devices) will exists, and currently there is no end of HDD use in sight.
- "attract opinion-based answers"
  In my question is about clarification of a certain claim and specifically emphasizes that it seeks evidence, not opinions.

So, please help, as I don't see why the question is off topic on this site.

PS: The second link in the boilerplate links to a question about "recommending software", so not really related the rest of the text (well, it is but only partially).

PPS: Meanwhile the question was (auto)deleted.

PPPS: I edited the question, removed the disputed part(s).

Comment: Clarification within a comment will not result in your question being reopened.  This is due to the fact commentary is considered temporary information

Comment: "Is there any actual evidence (a paper, a scientific article or similar, or at least a recorded test – like a YouTube video – that documents the error happening) that supports the claim that the URE is really certain (or at least very probable) under the described conditions (that is: in 12 TB read data)?" **You** are asking **us** to go away and find papers/articles/videos that support your claim that there is a discrepancy between two different sets of reported data. That is not something we do here ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't claim anything. I just want clarification on something. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533739) also asks something similar (true, on another site), to clear up some "claims". Or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/418126), or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/307567), or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/122359). Really don't see how mine is different.

Comment: It’s not clear how those other questions have anything to do with your question being closed or your question here?

Comment: @Ramhound My question is "is this true?" and they are too. I you think there is a substantial difference, please says what that is, so I can remove it from my question and make it on-topic. Or should I just strip my question to "I heard this, is it true?", like those are?

Comment: @DavidPostill I removed the pointed out part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the disputed part* of the question, flagged it with comment "I removed the disputed parts." and it was declined with  "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". (even if obviously the disputed part of the question was removed)

So I guess this issue is dead.

If you disagree, post a different answer.

* as per [this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13991/why-was-my-question-closed-as-off-topic#comment39704_13991) comment