# Request to reopen question 1736397

Tags: support

[My question](https://superuser.com/q/1736397/661137) has been closed immediately after I asked it. The closed message dialog links to another question: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/661137). The accepted answer with 57 upvotes describes 'How TO ASK questions that may require a software solution:'

> "I have <problem-x> that I don't know how to solve. I've already tried X, Y, Z, but those programs don't work because this or that. How do I do this?"

I'd argue this is pretty much the way I've phrased my question. Or isn't it?

Comment: Reopened but you need to provide more information as indicated in the comments.