# Why is question 480733 off topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, close-reasons, off-topic

https://superuser.com/questions/480733/communication-software-wanted-email-sms-im-phone-calls

Would you please explain, why this question is off topic?

I think I am a power user making high requirements on the software I use. There is a need for such a software I described and I think that I am not the only one with such needs.

Maybe the requirements could be improved, but that was not the reason that it was closed.

Right now I don't understand why the question is off topic. It would be nice if you can tell me, so that I can consider to improve and reopen the question or leave it closed. Thanks.

P.S.: I edited the question to make thing more clear.

Answer (score 7):

In general, question regarding **software recommendation** are very often considered off-topic.

If you want to know more about this ongoing issue, I would advise you to look into the numerous questions we already have discussing that topic. Such as:

- [Why was my software-rec question closed?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4622/why-was-my-software-rec-question-closed)
- [How literally does SU take "not about a shopping or buying recommendation"?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2088/how-literally-does-su-take-not-about-a-shopping-or-buying-recommendation)
- [Update the FAQ to disallow any product recommendation questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions)

And, last but certainly not least:

- [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software)

While you're giving a very extensive list of requirements, the question seems to boil down to "Here is my list of things I want, now go get it". That's usually not the type of software recommendation question we want or like. We prefer questions that deal with specific *problems*.

Now you're gonna tell me "*But I **do** have a specific problem! My problem is that I need that software!*"

However, it would be nice if the question is about a problem you encountered **while already trying to solve your issue** instead of looking for a specific piece of software that could provide the solution for your overall issue.

If you're thinking "*Hey, I'm just looking for a tool to get my communications in order. This is getting overly complicated.*", you can always drop by our little chat in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) and discuss your issue over there where you're not bound to these on-topic/off-topic rules.