# What should be done about old, abandoned questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Whenever a retag request comes about - or when I'm wading through /review I often come across old questions which haven't been answered, with low views & most of the times the questions are by anon users who've most probably done a hit-and-run.

Should these old questions be left as it is? Closed? Deleted?

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3158/help-us-clean-up-super-user

Answer (score 6):

You need to consider several things - which you've already mentioned:

- Can it be edited into something more useful?
- Does it have low views?
- Does the user still exist?

If, as you say, the question has low views and no votes and the user is either unregistered or doesn't exist any more then I think closing as too localised is the right thing to do. If it's got a zero score, down-voting to make it -1 will make it a candidate for the auto-delete bot.