# Make editing tag wikis more available to experienced users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, editing, tag-wiki

Currently, tag wikis have very stringent requirements for editing:

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with
>   more than 1500 reputation, provided:
>
> - They are in the top 20 answerers for
>     this tag
>
> or
>
> - They hold the bronze tag badge for
>     this tag

There has been a recent push from the SO team for [more wikifying](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). This has been discussed [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1856/help-create-and-maintain-community-faqs) and [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1182/critique-my-windows-7-tag-wiki), with tag wikis being a part of the process of making general information more readily available. Because of the high requirements for editing tag wikis though, very few exist. The only one I've actually seen is for [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7). I feel like some of the more experienced users here could easily contribute useful things to tag wikis if we were allowed to, but we currently can't.

Would it be possible for there to be a higher rep requirement which would allow users to edit *any* tag wiki? I understand the rationale for wanting a user to have experience in a subject area before writing about it generally, but right now, the limits in effect seem to be counterproductive. It would be nice if 3000+, or possibly a bit higher even, say 5000+ users could edit *any* tag wiki, regardless of how many rep points or answers they have in that tag.

Comment: Until it get's solved, you can bundle some proposed Wiki's in a Meta question if you want @nhinkle

Comment: Good suggestion @Ivo, I'll work on some when I have some free time. Do you have a sense for how likely this is to ever get done? I feel like tag wikis are essentially unused on super user right now, in large part because of this very problem.

Comment: Well by having users suggest them here (or in another question), there doesn't have to be an excuse. Anyway, the team often doesn't announce what they're going to change, so your guess is as good as mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the inception of [suggested edits](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/), tag wiki edits can be proposed by any user, thus solving this problem.