# Proposed tag wiki for Google Chrome

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-suggestion

> This is a **suggested tag wiki entry** for [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), a tag which very few users can edit and would benefit from having a more detailed tag wiki. Please see "[make editing tag wikis more accessible](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1867/make-editing-tag-wikis-more-available-to-experienced-users)" for more details.

### Short Description

Web browser developed and released by Google. Uses the Webkit rendering engine. Released for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

### Full text

[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) is the web browser developed by Google and is built upon the WebKit layout engine and application framework (used also by Safari). As of early 2011, Chrome held about 10% of the browser market share, according to [Net Applications](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0).

First released on 2 September 2008 on the Windows platform as a beta version, the stable public release hit on 11 December 2008. It has since been released for Mac OS X and Linux as well.

The name comes from the graphical user interface of web browsers which is called its chrome.

[image: Screenshot of chrome]

<sup>*Chrome 8 running on Windows 7*</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user should be able to submit an edit to an existing tag, the UI still needs a bit or work, it does not present you with the "your edit is pending" data on the wiki.

Comment: That feature is currently a bit broken, so I'm continuing to use this method in the meantime, as per IvoFlipse's advice. I've been discussing the brokenness with Waffles on MSO, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77169/

Comment: @nhinkle that pending edit of yours should be clear now, btw Waffles is my evil twin :)