# Proposed tag wiki for Microsoft Excel

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-suggestion

> This is a **suggested tag wiki entry** for [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel), a tag which very few users can edit and would benefit from having a more detailed tag wiki. Please see "[make editing tag wikis more accessible](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1867/make-editing-tag-wikis-more-available-to-experienced-users)" for more details.

### Excerpt

Microsoft Office Excel is a spreadsheet application written and distributed by Microsoft for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X. It features calculation, graphing tools, pivot tables and a macro programming language called VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

### Full text

Microsoft Office Excel is a spreadsheet application written and distributed by Microsoft for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X as part of the Microsoft Office suite.

The latest versions are Excel 2011 for OS X and Excel 2010 for Windows. Features include calculation, graphing tools, pivot tables and a macro programming language called VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). A new user-interface design, dubbed the "ribbon", was introduced with Excel 2007 for Windows. A similar UI was introduced to Excel 2011 for OS X.

Excel is the among most widely used spreadsheet programs, especially in business environments. The first version was introduced in 1993, and new versions have been released every 2-3 years since then.

[image: Microsoft Excel 2010]
<sup>*Microsoft Excel 2010 on Windows 7*</sup>

Comment: Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by Ivo Flipse on Jan 31, 2011.

Comment: What? No. It has a [status-completed] tag, it doesn't need an answer per se. Certainly not a "dummy answer". That's not how it works.

Comment: @nhinkle: than why was it still showing up in http://meta.superuser.com/unanswered ?

Comment: In fact, it looks like there needs to be an upvoted answer to get it off that list...

Comment: because it doesn't have an answer. It's not that big of a deal. Accepting a "dummy answer" is counterproductive. If Ivo had posted an answer saying, "OK, this is completed" then I would have accepted it, but a "dummy answer" _does not answer the question_. I appreciate your trying to help, and your flags on various other Meta questions have been quite helpful, but would suggest you delete this answer, as it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I edited your answer to a better format for denoting that a request is completed. On a related note, see this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65429/remove-questions-with-moderator-tags-from-the-unanswered-list